# A Sylow $p$-subgroup can be a subset of union of the rest of the Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Tags: finite-groups

Let G be a finite group and assume that number of the Sylow $p$-subgroups is more than one.

My question is this: "Can a Sylow $p$-subgroup be a subset of the union of the rest of the Sylow $p$-subgroups?"

I think this is impossible. Every Sylow $p$-subgroup contains some elements not contained in rest of the union, but I can not prove it nor find counterexample; if you show me one of them, I would be thankful.

Comment: Yes, [it can](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299682/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-does-every-sylow-p-subgroup-contain-an-element-not-in?rq=1).

Comment: Actually, counterexamples do exist. One example is $\operatorname{PSL}(2,11)$ with $p = 2$. I asked a similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299682/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-does-every-sylow-p-subgroup-contain-an-element-not-in)

Comment: thanks,it is very interesting for me since if one of them is subset of rest then it is true for all of them (by conjugation).I can't visualize the picture of sylow-p groups in that case and I beleive they may satisfy more beautiful properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general: take $G=S_3$, then $Syl_2(G)=\{\langle (1 2) \rangle,\langle(1 3)\rangle,\langle(2 3)\rangle\}$. Clearly each of these subgroups is *not* contained in the union of the others.