When does every element of Sylow $p$-subgroup is also a member of another Sylow $p$-subgroup?
Is it possible that every element of Sylow p-subgroup is also a member of another Sylow $p$-subgroup? Let $H_1$,$H_2$,....$H_n$ denotes different Sylow $p$-subgroup of group G, then for every $ x \in H_1$, $x \in H_j$ (for some $j \neq 1$).
Or put it equivalently, When does $$H_1 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j )$$
It's slightly different than $$H_2 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 2}}^n ( H_2 \cap H_j ) \text{ and } H_3 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 3}}^n ( H_3 \cap H_j )$$ ...etc (i.e. for all Sylow p-subgroups),
but I highly suspect $$H_1 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j ) \implies H_2 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 2}}^n ( H_2 \cap H_j ) \implies H_3 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 3}}^n ( H_3 \cap H_j )$$

Since every Sylow subgroup is conjugate to $H_1$ your suspicions in the final paragraph have an easy proof. (Which doesn't help with the real question, of course.)

Why is that, say $H_2 = gH_1g^{-1}$ and $$\begin{align} H_1 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1 \cap H_j ) \implies gH_1g^{-1}==g\bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_1^{-1} \cap H_j)g^{-1} =\bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( gH_1g^{-1} \cap gH_jg^{-1})  \implies H_2 =  \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_2 \cap gH_jg^{-1} ) \end{align}$$,
the RHS will have $H_2 \cap H_2$, so $H_2=H_2$, but it's different than $H_2 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 2}}^n ( H_2 \cap H_j ) $?

You'll only have a term $H_2\cap H_2$ if for some $j\ne 1$ we have $gH_j g^{-1}=H_2$ and we already have $H_2=gH_1g^{-1}$ and so $gH_j g^{-1}=gH_1 g^{-1}$ whence $H_j=H_1$ and so $j=1$ after all.

ok, we're trying to prove $H_2 =  \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 1}}^n ( H_2 \cap gH_jg^{-1} )$ is equivlent to $H_2 = \bigcup_{\substack{j=1, \ j \neq 2}}^n ( H_2 \cap H_j )$, why is that? $gH_jg^{-1} (j \neq 1)$ doesn't necessary produce all $H_1, H_3,...H_n$ ?

The element $g$ which carries $H_1$ to $H_2$  is a permutation of $H_1, H_2,\dots, H_n$. I have shown that for $j\ne 1$ the group $gH_jg^{-1}$ is not $H_2$. So the set of the $n-1$ conjugates of $H_2,\dots,H_n$ must be ${ H_k\mid k\ne 2}$.

yeap, you're correct.

Here's an example of order $180$. The idea is to find a group with a Sylow subgroup $P$, such that for every element $x\in P$, we have
\begin{equation*}
C_G(x)\not\le N_G(P)
\end{equation*}
This is sufficient because then for every $x\in P$, there's an element $g\in C_G(x)\setminus N_G(P)$ such that $x^g=x$ but $P^g\neq P$. So this arbitrary $x$ is also in the Sylow subgroup $P^g$.
First we construct the Abelian group $K$ of order $45$, with two generators: $c$ of order $3$, and $d$ of order $15$. So $K\cong\langle c\rangle\times\langle d\rangle$. Now let $P=\langle a,b\rangle$ be a non-cyclic group of order $4$.We form the semidirect product
\begin{equation*}
G = K\rtimes P
\end{equation*}
Based on the following actions:
\begin{align*}
c^a &= c^{-1}\\
c^b &= c^{-1}\\
d^a &= d^4\\
d^b &= d^{-4}
\end{align*}
Now $N_G(P)=P$, so any element not in $P$ will conjugate $P$ to a different Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$. But
\begin{align*}
  d^5 &\in C_G(a)\\
  d^3 &\in C_G(b)\\
  c &\in C_G(ab) 
\end{align*}

More examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299682/if-p-is-an-odd-prime-does-every-sylow-p-subgroup-contain-an-element-not-in

(+1) The key idea is in the first paragraph. Using that I think you can get a slightly more transparent example by taking not a group of order $45$ but one of order $27$, elementary abelian. generated by $c,d,f$ say. Then let $a$ fix $c$ and invert $d,f$; $b$ fix $d$ and invert $f,c$; so that $ab$ fixes $f$ and inverts $c,d$. By symmetry all that needs checked is that $C(a)\not\le N_G(P)$  which is clear. But the key idea is yours.

@ancientmathematician: yes that's true and in fact using the base group of order 27 I think gives the smallest example. Even the group of order 420 might be better since then it's clear that the Sylow 2-subgroup is self-normalizing. I only used 180 because I was trying to find an example of order 60, and needed to add a second 3-factor to make the centralizers work out.
