# How many $p$-elements does $G$ have?

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let $G$ be a group with a non normal $p$-sylow subgroup $P$.
Is there any information about the number of $p$-elements(an element with $p$-power order) of $G$?

Comment: In general, nothing more non-trivial than what's already in Sylow; one also needs an idea of the intersection of Sylow $p$'s; this is a rather delicate question, I'd say. But, you must first work out what Sylow tells you and ask more precise question.

Comment: I agree with kan. The question is too general. You need to ask something more specific if you want a helpful answer. (As a general rule, questions of the type "what can we say about ...?" should be made more specific.)

Comment: The only situation where you can say something precise a priori is that of $p$ dividing exactly $|G|$. In this case the $p$-Sylows are cyclic of order $p$, and intersect each other trivially, so there are $n_p(p-1)$ elements of order $p$ in $G$.

Comment: I've asked some more specific versions of this question that might be interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/is-there-a-group-with-exactly-92-elements-of-order-3

Comment: I have also asked a related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278600/lower-bounds-on-the-number-of-elements-in-sylow-subgroups)

Comment: @m.k. good to know. That was actually a research direction of mine. Let me know if you are interested in my results. No one else was :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt: I'm interested! I spent a lot of time with this and other things related to solutions of $x^n = 1$.. are you going to post an answer or should I send you an email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find out some general properties, but nothing precise really unless you have more information.

Let $G$ be a finite group. Denote by $a_p(G)$ the number of $p$-elements of $G$.

Frobenius' theorem states that when $n$ divides the order $G$, the number of solutions to $x^n = 1$ in $G$ is a multiple of $n$. Note that $a_p(G)$ is the number of solutions to $x^{p^\alpha} = 1$, where $p^\alpha$ is the largest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$. Hence Frobenius' theorem implies that $a_p(G)$ is a multiple of $p^\alpha$, say $a_p(G) = p^\alpha r$.

Now the number of elements of order $k$ in $G$ is a multiple of $\varphi(k)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. Thus for any $1 \leq l \leq \alpha$, it follows that $p-1$ divides the number of elements of order $p^l$ in $G$. Hence $p-1$ divides $a_p(G) - 1$. In particular $p-1$ divides $r-1$, and thus

$$a_p(G) = p^{\alpha}(t(p-1) + 1)$$

for some integer $t \geq 0$.

Let $n_p(G)$ be the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$, so $n_p(G) \equiv 1 \mod{p}$ by Sylow's theorem. It is possible to deduce some small things about $a_p(G)$ if we know $n_p(G)$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278600/lower-bounds-on-the-number-of-elements-in-sylow-subgroups) (SE) and [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/119421/lower-bounds-on-the-number-of-elements-in-sylow-subgroups) (MO). For example, G. A. Miller proved that

- If $n_p(G) = 1$, then $a_p(G) = p^\alpha$.
- If $n_p(G) = p+1$, then $a_p(G) = p^{\alpha+1}$.
- If $n_p(G) > p+1$, then $a_p(G) \geq p^\alpha(2p - 1)$.

Comment: Your answer include some nice thing that I havn't known before. Thanks for your tips. Do you have any refrence for two last line?

Comment: @Adeleh: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233071/if-a-finite-group-has-geq-p1-sylow-p-subgroups-of-order-pn-then-ther). Specifically, Miller proves in pg 79-80 of "Theory and Applications of Finite Groups" (1916) that $a_p(G) > p^{\alpha+1}$ when $n_p(G) > p+1$. Now we can apply the fact that $a_p(G) = p^{\alpha}(t(p-1) + 1)$ to improve this to $a_p(G) \geq p^{\alpha}(2p-1)$. This improvement is from Miller's paper "Some Deductions From Frobenius's Theorem" (1942), it is near the end of the paper: [link to paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/28/6/251.full.pdf).